# jquery :contains() match limit?

Tags: jquery, text, find, contains

```
$("div:contains(' 1434')").parent().addClass('date');
```

class is added to ALL divs. I know, class/id would help but the html is tag soup and I can do nothing about it. Is there any way to restrict the match to just the **element that contains the  text directly**?

Comment: What do you mean by text directly?

Comment: How big is the DOM scope that you are searching?

Comment: @Vega the element that contains the text directly? sorry, english is not my primary lang

Comment: If there are multiple divs containing 1434, it will return an array/jso of dom references.  I would recommend using $.each($("div:contains('1434')"), function(){$(this).parent().addClass('date')});  It'll work more often.

Comment: Also, wherever possible, you want to use ID selectors to reference particular DOM elements.  IDs are keys in the DOM so it searches and returns an element reference fast.  Using class selectors and selector functions is notoriously slow, but it can work in smaller pages just fine.  Just a best practice to think about using ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `has` to get the parent elements, and `not` to get the innermost elements:

```
var d = $('div:contains(" 1434")');
var p = d.has(d);
d.not(p).parent().addClass('border');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/JFHjG/

Comment: whoa, there! :D I guess you've earned 193K ratings for a reason! :D